# Does simulating price as GBM automatically implies risk neutrality?

Tags: option-pricing, risk-neutral-measure

I am using a dynamic programming approach to price European options where formulate the pricing as a  discrete-time continuous-space Markov Decision process. The MDP is risk-sensitive as in I don’t take expected value of hedge portfolio to be the option fair price but rather I add a “risk-premium” which is equal to discounted variance of the hedge portfolio. By doing this I can negate the assumption of risk-neutrality.

But since Dynamic programming needs a model for the world, I have to assume the stock price dynamics as a GBM. My question is even though I incorporate risk in options in the action-value function of the MDP, does using GBM which by girsanov theorm is risk-neutral creeps in the risk-neutral assumption in the formulation?